# Realising level polymorphic subsets within records

Tags: set, subset, agda

Using the notion of subsets as predicates,

```
ℙ : ∀ {b a} → Set a → Set (a ⊔ suc b)
ℙ {b} {a} X = X → Set b
```

I'd like to consider structures endowed with a predicate on subsets,

```
record SetWithAPredicate {a c} : Set {!!} where
  field
   S : Set a
   P : ∀ {b} → ℙ {b} S → Set c
```

This is an ill-formed construction due to the level quantification used in `ℙ`. Everything works fine when I use `S, P` as parameters to a module, but I'd like them to be records so that I can form constructions on them and give instances of them.

I've tried a few other things, such as moving the level `b` of `ℙ` inside the definition via an existential but then that led to metavaraible trouble. I also tried changing the type of `P`,

```
P : ℙ {a} S → Set c
```

but then I can no longer ask for, say, the empty set to have the property:

```
P-⊥ : P(λ _ → ⊥)
```

This is not well typed since `Set != Set a` ---I must admit, I tried to use `Level.lift` here, but failed to do so.
More generally, this will also not allow me to express closure properties, such as `P` is closed under arbitrary unions ---this is what I'm really interested in.

I understand that I can just avoid level polymorphism,

```
ℙ' : ∀ {a} → Set a → Set (suc zero ⊔ a)
ℙ' {a} X = X → Set
```

but then simple items such as the largest subset,

```
ℙ'-⊤ : ∀ {i} {A : Set i} → ℙ' A
ℙ'-⊤ {i} {A} = λ e → Σ a ∶ A • a ≡ e
-- Σ_∶_•_ is just syntax for Σ A (λ a → ...)
```

will not even typecheck!

Perhaps I did not realise the notion of subset as predicate appropriately ---any advice would be appreciated. Thank-you!

Comment: What do you mean by "closed under unions"? Each `P : ℙ A` is like subset on `A`, but the usual notions of union act on `Set`-s, not on elements of `A`, unless `A = Set i`.

Comment: the union of subsets can be realised as an existential/sum type; in particular,

     A ∪ B = λ e → A e ⊎ B e

Comment: But then `A` or `B` are not closed under union since their union is yet another subset/property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to lift `b` out from `P` like this

```
record SetWithAPredicate {a c} b : Set {!!} where
  field
   S : Set a
   P : ℙ {b} S → Set c
```

Yes, this is ugly and annoying, but that's how it's done in Agda ([an example](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Category/Monad/Indexed.agda#L15) from standard library: `_>>=_` is not properly universe polymorphic). `Lift` can help sometimes, but it quickly [gets out of hand](https://github.com/effectfully/Eff/blob/master/Resources/Core.agda#L47).

> Perhaps I did not realise the notion of subset as predicate
>   appropriately ---any advice would be appreciated.

Your definition is correct, but there is another one, see 4.8.3 in Conor McBride's [lecture notes](https://github.com/pigworker/SSGEP-DataData/blob/master/notes.pdf).

Comment: I am now the sad :'( ---but appreciative of your reply.